# API feed for OHLC / VWAP data in (close to) real-time

Tags: exchanges, api

I'm interested in the OHLC / VWAP data (both historical and recent) provided via API to be used by external charting application.
I don't want to use `trades` methods as whole process should be as lightweight as possible, `trades` method is redundant due to history loading speed.
Combining [bitcoincharts.com](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/) csv historical trades with markets API recent trades would be kind of error prone.

Another option would be to access the following data:

1. visit bitcoincharts chart: http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/krakenEUR
2. below the chart in the left corner click on `Load raw data`
3. and just download those data

I've checked the page and data appears in `tbody` in the following `div` after click on `Load raw data`:

```
<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="load_table();return false;">Load raw data</a>
  <table class="data" id="chart_table" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th><th>Open</th><th>High</th><th>Low</th><th>Close</th><th>Volume (BTC)</th><th>Volume (Currency)</th><th>Weighted Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Is there any easy way to access those data similarly to API?

Another way is to ask markets for such method, kraken already provide such: https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XBTCZEUR&interval=60&since=1416160800
I've just asked for such method on hitbtc market, you can track/contribute here: https://github.com/hitbtc-com/hitbtc-api/issues/7

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to retrieve raw OHLC and VWAP data from bitcoincharts.com in a not-too-difficult manner using JavaScript (as well as jQuery) by extracting the relevant tabular data provided at http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/krakenEUR#rg60ztgSzm1g10zm2g25zv and passing it to an external charting application.

Unfortunately, extracting HTML data from an external website using JavaScript can sometimes be a complicated process, due to the presence of content security and [same origin policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) (these issues apply particularly to Google Chrome).

The following question on StackOverflow explores an easy way to retrieve external HTML using jQuery and AJAX (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax).
A simple solution using the aforementioned method could be similar to the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8", //maybe "ISO-8859-1"
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});

$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
  encodeURIComponent('http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/krakenEUR#rg60ztgSzm1g10zm2g25zv') + '&callback=?',
    function(data) {
        console.log("> ", data);
        $("#chart_table" tbody tr).find("td").html(data.contents);
});
```

Essentially, this method of extracting data from an API or website would depend on what language you are using, and whether you are implementing a back-end. Perhaps placing a similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), a site dedicated to programming questions would return better suited results.

**Edit:** More information regarding bypassing same origin policies can be found at [Christian Heilmann's blog](http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/), a developer evangelist with the Mozilla Network.
Information regarding utilising GET and POST requests can be found at [Doncho Minkov's SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/DonchoMinkov/external-data-access-with-jquery), however, this may not be the most effective way to access data when restricted by same origin policies.